# how to find objects in a rotated image?

Tags: image-processing

Recently i use the function matchTemplate of opencv to find objects in target image. But when searching in the rotated target image the results are bad. After searching for relevant information I want to use Pyramid matching to solve this problems. Are there any good suggestions?

Comment: You could use scale and rotation invariant features like SIFT.

Comment: Yes, It's a solution. When use SIFT how can a know the rotation angle.

Comment: You can use findHomography to calculate the transformation between your Keypoints. [This example](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) could be useful. With the homographie you could calculate the rotation.

Comment: Thx. I know the Vison software Halcon has operator can solve this problem. We can't see the code but call the function interface. I want use opensource to solve this like based opencv.

Comment: I think using sift, surf or another feature detector in OpenCv is the easiest solution. An alternative could be the FFT-algorithm from [this paper](http://www.lira.dist.unige.it/teaching/SINA_10/slides-current/fourier-mellin-paper.pdf) or the algorithm from [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c965/0f78bf9d18eba3850281841dc7ddd20e8d5e.pdf).

Comment: Yes, I have tested surf and Sometimes it really work. Maybe image pyramid is also a solution. Thanks for your suggest paper and I will try them. .